# refers to a value, but is being used as a type here

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I am new in typescript and node.js and also I am Trying to use typescript and node.js I create a model with mongoose and import it to my users.service.ts file but when I use to get this error
`CreateUserDto' refers to a value but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof CreateUserDto'?`
I create a file by the name users.ts this is my model and also create a file by the name of users.service.ts the code of these files you can find below please help me I can fix the error thank you so much.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MCLu.jpg)
Model: users.ts

```
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
// import IUser from "../interface/users"
import { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface IUser extends Document {
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String,
  password: String
}

const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
});
export default mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
```

users.service.ts

```
import UsersDao from '../daos/users.dao';
import { CRUD } from '../../common/interfaces/crud.interface';
import CreateUserDto from "../model/users";
import { PutUserDto } from '../dto/put.user.dto';
import { PatchUserDto } from '../dto/patch.user.dto';

class UsersService implements CRUD {

    async create(resource: CreateUserDto) {
        return UsersDao.addUser(resource);
    }

    async deleteById(id: string) {
        return UsersDao.removeUserById(id);
    }

    async list(limit: number, page: number) {
        return UsersDao.getUsers();
    }

    async patchById(id: string, resource: PatchUserDto) {
        return UsersDao.patchUserById(id, resource);
    }

    async readById(id: string) {
        return UsersDao.getUserById(id);
    }

    async putById(id: string, resource: PutUserDto) {
        return UsersDao.putUserById(id, resource);
    }

    async getUserByEmail(email: string) {
        return UsersDao.getUserByEmail(email);
    }
}

export default new UsersService();
```

Comment: Upgrade your project to typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CreateUserDto` is a `mongoose` model, this is not a valid type descriptor for typescript. You can read about all the valid ts types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html).

What you want to do is use the `IUser` interface you created instead like so:

```
async create(resource: IUser) {
   return UsersDao.addUser(resource);
}
```

Comment: I want to save data in MongoDB or find users from my database but I can't do these with interface

Comment: the interface just describes the type for the ts compiler, it does not contain any actual data. You can see this when you compile the code to javascript the interfaces "dispear".

Comment: I remove the user interface and just create a user model using mongoose